# fabric.js rotate object around canvas center smoothly

Tags: fabricjs

I try to rotate an object around the canvas center smoothly using a slider,
I use fabric.util.rotatePoint to find the new center point and set the new angle,but it seems not exactly around the center point and the object position is jumping.

https://jsfiddle.net/j0g1tLsb/26/

here is my code doing this:

```
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { width: innerWidth, height: innerHeight });
canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;
canvas.preserveObjectStacking = true;

const rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 300,
  height: 150,
  left: 400,
  top: 400,
  fill: "lightgray",
    originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const centerPoint = new fabric.Circle({ 
   originX: 'center',
   originY: 'center',
   top: innerHeight/2, 
   left: innerWidth/2,
   radius: 10, 
   fill: 'red',
   hasControls: false,
   selectable:false
});


const log = new fabric.Text('', {
    left: 30,
  top: 30,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  fontSize: 18,
  evented: false,
  selectable: false
});

canvas.add(rect, centerPoint, log);

document.getElementById('img-rotation').oninput = function() {
      rect.set('angle', this.value);

      var posNewCenter = fabric.util.rotatePoint(
                            rect.getCenterPoint(),
                            canvas.getVpCenter(),
                            fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.value)
                        );

                        rect.set({
                            left: posNewCenter.x,
                            top: posNewCenter.y,
                            angle: this.value
                        });

      log.set('text', `angle: ${Math.round(rect.angle)} \nleft: ${rect.left} \ntop: ${rect.top}`);
      canvas.requestRenderAll();
    };


rect.on('modified', () => {
    log.set('text', `angle: ${Math.round(rect.angle)} \nleft: ${rect.left} \ntop: ${rect.top}`);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in getting center point from the rectangle every time. You need just set new Point from the original rectangle position.

```
var posNewCenter = fabric.util.rotatePoint(
    new fabric.Point(400, 400), //here is your mistake
    canvas.getVpCenter(),
    fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.value)
);
rect.set({
    left: posNewCenter.x,
    top: posNewCenter.y,
    angle: this.value
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0g1tLsb/62/)

**UPDATE:**

In order of the modification of the Rectangle you need to use `object:modified` event to reassign `top` and `left` coordinates.

First of all declare top and left variables and use them inside rectangle object:

```
let top = 400;
let left = 400;
const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  ...
  left: left,
  top: top,
  ...
  targetObj: 'rectangle' //you can use any value or ID, it's only for targeting purpose
});
```

Then you need to check when object is modified. If event is fired then check if it is rectangle.

```
canvas.on('object:modified', (e) => {
    if (e.target.hasOwnProperty('targetObj') && e.target.targetObj === 'rectangle') {
    left = e.target.get('left');
    top = e.target.get('top');
  }
})
```

Finally, use left and top variables inside oninput event of the slider:

```
var posNewCenter = fabric.util.rotatePoint(
    new fabric.Point(left, top),
    canvas.getVpCenter(),
    fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.value)
);
```

Working updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0g1tLsb/74/)

Comment: Thanks @Observer, 
It did work when the rect is at it's original place, but if I move the rect to a new place then slide, it still use (400,400) as it's center point but not updated to the new location.

Comment: I try to add a rectCenter to record center value, still not work
https://jsfiddle.net/j0g1tLsb/67/